# Android Studio build fail with minSDK=29

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-min-sdk

I have Android Studio build problem.

Build fails only when changing the minSdk=29 with follwing error.
( It's OK with minSdk=28 )

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aaa"
        minSdkVersion 29  // build fails with 29, it's OK with 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Fail messages on Android Studio build console

```
    - Build: build failed

       - Run build :

         ...

         Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException


       - Andriod issues: (1 error)

         Dex file with version '38' cannot be used with min sdk level '29'.
```

If anyone resolved this problem, please share your know-hows.

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element Please read on this . `android:minSdkVersion`: 

""An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
 application to run""

The latest version of Android is Android Pie which uses SDK version 28.

Comment: try to add compile "com.android.tools:r8:1.4.93" to the build dependencies (not your app dependencies). Something like:         `classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.93' classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`

Comment: This problem was resolved after updating Android Studio version 3.5 !

Thank you.  Gabriele Mariotti,  sunil sunny.

Comment: Clean & Rebuild, and/or Invalidate caches & restart solved my issue.

Comment: I am getting this error with Android Studio and gradle 3.6.2. Any solution other than downgrading?

Answer (score 13):

I came across this recently when updating a project for Android studio 3.5.3 to 3.6.3, however I manually changed `gradle-wrapper.properties` and the project's `build.gradle` before even opening the project.

In my case I was able to clean the build, delete the `.gradle` and `.idea` folders and rebuild without issue.

**Edit:** As stated in the comments, it is worthwhile to try a clean-rebuild first, rather than the "Scorched Earth" approach of deleting `.gradle` and `.idea` folders. Deleting them will take longer to recover from and blow away all your nice IDE settings!

Comment: Cleaning the build and then running 'Make Project' fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of latest gradle version : 
**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'**

in **Android 6.0 and lower android versions**. In order to fix it you can downgrade the gradle version as follows :

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'**

It will run on all android versions perfectly.